# How do you find what wordpress theme someone is using?

Tags: wordpress, themes

How do you find what theme someone is using, for example what theme does the official wordpress blog use?

Here are the links :

```
http://en.blog.wordpress.com

http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2006/08/17/forgotten-birthday/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme being used is called h4.

You can find this out by looking at where the style sheet is located. The style sheet code from this page is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://s2.wp.com/wp-content/themes/h4/style.css?m=1345845332g&amp;5" media="screen" />
```

so you can see that the theme is stored in `wp-content/themes/h4`.

I would assume that h4 is a custom theme and wont be available publicly though.

**Edit**

This website is also useful for finding a wordpress theme as you just stick in the url and it pulls all the meta information (if there is any) from the CSS for you.

http://whatwpthemeisthat.com/